# Is $R/bR$ reduced if $R$ is reduced and $\operatorname{Ann}(b)$ is a minimal prime of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a noetherian, reduced ring. Let $P = \operatorname{Ann}_R(b)$ with $b \in R$ be a minimal prime of $R$.

> Does this imply that $R/bR$ is reduced?

Of course, the property in question is equivalent to $bR$ being radical.

Considering coordinate rings of affine curves over a field $k$, we have for instance $R = k[x,y]/(fgh)$ where $f,g,h \in k[x,y]$ are irreducible. Then $R$ is reduced. The minimal primes of $R$ are given by
$$P_1 = (f) = \operatorname{Ann}_R(gh),\quad P_2 = (g) = \operatorname{Ann}_R(fh),\quad P_3 = (h) = \operatorname{Ann}_R(fg).$$

Now for $P = P_1= (f)$ we have $b = gh$ and $R/bR \cong k[x,y]/f$ which is reduced since $f$ was irreducible.

Now I am curious whether this generalizes. For me it's like one of those general questions which goes like *What can we tell in general about such $b \in R$ with $\operatorname{Ann}_R(b)$ a minimal prime of $R$*? For now, I am concerned about the above question.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $R$ is a domain then for all $b \in R$, $b\ne 0$, $\operatorname{Ann}_R(b) = 0$ which is a minimal prime of $R$, but not every factor ring of a domain is reduced.

Specifically, let $R = \Bbb Z$, $b = 4$. Then $\operatorname{Ann}_R(b) = 0$, but $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ is not reduced.

Comment: Well, that's true. But do you also have such an example for $P \neq 0$, i.e. $R$ not a domain?

Comment: @windsheaf What about $R=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$, and $b=(4,0)$?

Comment: @user26857 This is a nice answer. Thank you.

Comment: @user26857 This answers the question. But now I see that if $P$ is *given*, then we may *choose* a $b \in R$ such that $P = \operatorname{Ann}(b)$ and $b$ not a square. Does the statement hold in that case?

Comment: @windsheaf I suggest you should ask that as a separate question (but link to it here as they are related)