# Does $\operatorname{Ann}(d) = \operatorname{Ann}(b)$ together with $d \in \operatorname{Rad}(bR)$ imply $d \in bR$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ann}{Ann}\DeclareMathOperator{\Rad}{Rad}$Let $R$ be a noetherian, reduced ring which is not an integral domain (and may also not be factorial).

> Let $P$ be a minimal prime of $R$. Is it possible to find $b \in R$ with $P = \Ann(b)$ and $bR$ radical?

**What I tried:** Consider a non-zero element $d \in \Rad(bR)$. By assumption we have $\Ann(d) \subseteq \Ann(b) = P$ since $P$ is prime and $d \neq 0$. Moreover, since $R$ is reduced, we obtain equality, i.e. $\Ann(d) = \Ann(b) = P$. But I don't know how to proceed from here on.

Note that we may change $b \in R$ in any way that preserves $\Ann(b) = P$. We may also assume (if necessary) that $R$ is finite free over some principal ideal domain (since the original motivation is from geometry where I consider a projective curve lying finitely over the projective line).

I am grateful for any kind of help.

---

**Edit:** *I edited the question since it wasn't clear what I meant.*

---

This question is related to the following: [Is $R/bR$ reduced if $R$ is reduced and $\operatorname{Ann}(b)$ is a minimal prime of $R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991205/is-r-br-reduced-if-r-is-reduced-and-operatornameannb-is-a-minimal-pri)

Comment: Isn't this just a rephrasing of the previous question? ($d \in \text{Rad}(bR)$ implies $d \in bR$) if and only if ($R/bR$ is reduced).

Comment: Your question appears to have been answered in your link. What is different between these two questions? (Aside from $R$ isn't an integral domain here, which is hardly a restriction) Take $k[x,y]/(xy)$, then $\Ann(x^2)=(y)$, which is a minimal prime, but $(x^2)$ is not radical.

Comment: @jgon The question comprises whether it is always possible to choose $b \in R$ such that $bR$ is radical. In your example, $(x)$ is radical.

Comment: @windsheaf That's not what this question says. Nowhere in this question does it even imply that that's what you're asking. I'm then a bit confused about what you're asking, are you asking if every reduced noetherian ring has a principal radical ideal? Please edit and clarify